# How to prevent Silverlight from installing?

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2016, silverlight

How to prevent Silverlight from being installed again and again?

Since I installed MS Office 365/2016, Silverlight is getting installed with every Office update. Every time I notice it has installed, I immediately uninstall it. But how can I prevent it from being installed at first place?

Windows 7 SP1;
MS Office 365 ProPlus

Comment: What is wrong with having it installed? Aside from it being yet another piece of bloatware is it preventing your computer from working or otherwise impeding your work? I'm not saying you shouldn't remove it, but you probably have about 15 to 20 MS Visual C runtimes of various versions installed and this is not really much different to that, it's just another piece of software to ignore and block in your browser.

Comment: That said, if you can find the name of the installer for silver light you can block it from running by editing the registry: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/8739/restrict-users-to-run-only-specified-programs-in-windows-7/

Comment: Silverlight is like Flash, not like a C-runtime. I always avoid having installed any internet software that I do not use, for security reasons. Anyway, thanks for the hint, but can this be turned off directly in the Office? While Office installs were managed by the Windows Update, there was much much better control on which update to install and what to exclude.